# Hide sidenav on large screens

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I am using VMWARE Clarity and Angular, and I have an application set up to hide the sidenav on small screens according to the documentation. I would also like to have the hamburger menu on large screens, and be able to show/hide the nav on large screens. Is there a way do to this natively in Clarity, or do I need to figure out my own way. I looked through the doc but couldn't find anything for this scenario. I wanted to check here before I start hacking it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Clarity has a collapsible vertical nav: https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.12/vertical-nav

It doesn't completely disappears and doesn't use a hamburger icon in the header,  but it probably does what you are looking for, meaning have more screen real estate for the actual content of the page.

Comment: Thank you, I was not thinking of the vertical Nav! Yes that will do what I need!